# Index out of bound of the array in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I'm trying to put a 2D array into 2 arrays but I keep getting index out of the bounds of the array. The reason you might ask of why I'm doing this is so that I can store it in a `viewstate` object so I don't have to continuously retrieve my data.

The code I've been trying to use is this:

```
Dim testArray As String() = {}



testArray(0) = dataArray(0, 1)
```

and if there is a way to store a 2D array in a `viewstate`,  let me know. Thanks!

Oh, I'm sorry, Heres the dataArray code

```
 Private Function getDataArray() As Array
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim DT As DataTable
    Dim TA As New DSOldOrdersTableAdapters.TA
    DT = getOldOrders()
    ReDim dataArray(3, DT.Rows.Count - 1)
    For x = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
        dataArray(0, x) = DT.Rows(x).Item("SO")
        dataArray(1, x) = DT.Rows(x).Item("Customer")
        dataArray(2, x) = DT.Rows(x).Item("ShipBy")
    Next
    Return dataArray
End Function
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Is this different from the `Index was outside the bounds of the array` question you posted yesterday? If so, we need to see the code in question.

Comment: All I have is what I have up there. I can't figure out why i'm getting the index is out of array.

Comment: @prncoltrane I don't believe I posted a question yesterday like this

Comment: Oh @prncoltrane I see what you mean, no this is not the same problem I got that one answered

Comment: The cause is the same: you're trying to access an index that's outside the array bounds. You *must* have more code than this: at the very least, `testArray` and `dataArray` must be declared somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, Heres the dataArray code Private Function getDataArray() As Array Dim x As Integer Dim DT As DataTable Dim TA As New DSOldOrdersTableAdapters.TA DT = getOldOrders() ReDim dataArray(3, DT.Rows.Count - 1) For x = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1 dataArray(0, x) = DT.Rows(x).Item("SO") dataArray(1, x) = DT.Rows(x).Item("Customer") dataArray(2, x) = DT.Rows(x).Item("ShipBy") Next Return dataArray End Function I call this when the page loads and then store it back into data array dataArray = getDataArray()

test array is declared as

Dim testArray As String() = {}

Comment: One last thing, When I display custName.text = dataArray(0, ) into custName label, I get the data, but trying to store the data into a 1D array I get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim testArray As String() = {}
testArray(0) = dataArray(0, 1)
```

You're declaring testArray and assigning an empty array to it. Because the array is zero-length, there *is* no index 0, so trying to assign to `testArray(0)` results in an index out of bounds exception.

You need to ReDim the testArray variable, or change your assignment:

```
Dim testArray As String() = {}
ReDim testArray(0)
testArray(0) = dataArray(0, 1)
'or
Dim testArray As String() = {dataArray(0,1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring

```
 Dim testArray As String() = {}
```

created a string array with a dimension set to zero

So testArray is useless without a dimensioning of at least one element.
Writing

```
testArray(0) = dataArray(0, 1)
```

cause the Index Out Of bound exception

Probably you need an array of the same length of your datatable rows.
But, why all the effort to use an array in  this context?.
A List(Of String) is a better solution

```
Dim testValues = new List(Of String)()
testValues.Add(dataArray(0,1))
```

In this way you don't need to know how big the testArray should be and you could use the List as an array in every place where it is required to have the array

```
Dim soValue = testValues(0)
```

or

```
testValues.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're having would be because, the element you're trying to refer to is not present in the Array. Index of an array starts at `0`, so always try to make sure, you're refering the last element to be `(maxElements - 1)`. Otherwise it would cause an error and you'll see this error.

Comment: in my original loop when trying to do it, I did have dataArray.length - 1 looping through adding it to the test array, was getting the out of index array. Now I am literally just trying to get the first piece of data into the test array so i'm trying testArray(0) = dataArray(0, 0), nothing else, and i'm still getting out of index array. @afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan

Comment: Edited my orginal post @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan